# ALB Target Health check failing with the status - "Health checks failed with these codes: [401]"

Tags: http-status-code-401, aws-application-load-balancer, health-check

I am trying to figure out why my ALB Target Group is not passing the health check and throwing a 401 (Unauthorized) error. Details are:

ALB Listener 443 forwarding to Target Group.

AWS Linux RHEL 7.9 Server.

Application Load Balancer.

I have my ALB Target Group Health Check Setup like so-

Protocol: HTTP

Path: /

Port: traffic port

Default threshold and timeouts

In my Security Group I have port 80, 443, and 22 open for inbound traffic.

I have added 401 as a success code to the Health check tab because it's throwing a 401 (Unauthorized) error, but when I try to browse with the ALB DNS name, I get the Unauthorized error page. Please suggest

The site is operational however, when I attempt to browse using the PrivateIP:port

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there! I have the same issue with 401 health checks, did you manage to figure out what was the case?